# Limit angular ng-repeat to certain rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

For example if i had the json dataset here of all languages of books:

```
$scope.data = [{
    "title": "Alice in wonderland",
    "author": "Lewis Carroll",
    "lang": ["en"]
}, {
    "title": "Journey to the West",
    "author": "Wu Cheng'en",
    "lang": ["ch"]
}]
```

And I simply wanted to display exclusively english books, would I be able to do this purely using a filter in ng-repeat?

E.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data | filter:d.lang='en'" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
    {{d.title}}
</div>
```

I **do not** want to do it via any sort of form control (radio button etc). Would this be possible?

-EDIT- Thanks @GrizzlyMcBear for leading me down the right path! I got it to work with a slightly different filter function (which I'll paste below)

```
app.filter('MyFilter', function() {

    var out = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(i) {

      if (i.lang[0] === 'en') {
        out.push(i);
      }
    })

    return out;
  }

});
```

and in the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data | MyFilter" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
    {{d.title}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use angular's [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter),

I would also suggest that you use a function in the filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in collection | filter:filteringFunction" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
    {{d.title}}
</div>
```

This way gives you more freeeeeedom (you're more than welcome to shout it Mel Gibson style ;-) )
in filtering your data by introducing more complex filtering logic.

```
    var filteredLang = "en";

    function filterByBookLanguage(collectionItem) {
        var result = false;

        if (collectionItem.lang[0] === filteredLang) {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    $scope.filteringFunction = filterByBookLanguage;
```

Now If you wish, you can also change the comperator function - `filterByBookLanguage`
(my terminology).

Say that your boss *suddenly* wants you to change the filtering logic from filtering books
into filtering by the author's name. Now all you have to do is add this condition:

```
    if (bossWantsToChangeFilter) {
        $scope.filteringFunction = filterByAuthorName;
    } else {
        $scope.filteringFunction = filterByBookLanguage;
    }
```

All you have to remember is to write the comperator function with the current filtered item
as an argument and update the compared value of the language/author name
in the location you've found convenient ($scope, local variable, service etc.).

Comment: I got my dataset slightly wrong-- lang is now an array as opposed to a string before. I've tried to do collectionItem.lang[0] === "en" but it doesnt seem to filter anything...

Comment: @GwenWong can you provide a working plunker (any other similar thing), also - when you run my comperator function, please place a debugger command before the if (collectionItem.lang[0] === "en") condition, let me know what you see in the first element of the languages array :)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data | filter: { lang : 'en'} " style="margin-bottom: 2%">
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/c1d0dtcs/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for replying! I got the dataset slightly wrong, instead of it being 'lang':'en' its morerather 'lang':['en']...and that seems to not work with the code above...